# How to clone a test plan keeping the test case original area path?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-test-manager

Currently when we clone a test plan in Microsoft Test Manager we need to specify an area path for the cloned test cases. This is bad when we use the area path for TFS Teams or we use it for product area management and the cloned test cases end up having all the same area path.

I have already shared this idea on [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6049283-make-it-possible-to-clone-the-test-plan-but-keepin), but I would like to know if there is an workaround for this. A clone tool would also be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool may be exactly what you need: [TFS 2013 Tester Power Tool - Bulk Copy Test Cases for Microsoft Test Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cdc43e42-0dd3-49a5-bf98-9f44a372f14e)